# Find and replace string containing forward slash in ksh using a variable

Tags: string, variables, replace, ksh

In a file (`file1.txt`) I have `/path1/|value1` (a path, followed by a value). I need to find the line containing that (unique) path and then change the value. So the line should end up as: `/path1/|value2`.

The challenge is that the `/path1/`, `value1` and `value2` parts are both contained within variables.

When I don't use a variable, I can use ([thanks to this page](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq3.html)):

```
sed '/path1/s/value1/value2/g' file1.txt > copyfile1.txt
```

(This creates a copy of the original file which I can later overwrite the original file using `mv`.)

This is just searching for `path1`. To search for `/path1/` I can use:

```
sed '/\/path1\//s/value1/value2/g' file1.txt > copyfile1.txt
```

Using [the answers to this question about extracting a substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730664/how-can-i-extract-a-substring-after-a-certain-string-in-ksh) I can put the `/path1/`, `value1` and `value2` parts into variables.

So my current code is:

```
sed '/'"${PATH}"'/s/'"${PREVIOUS_VALUE}"'/'"${NEW_VALUE}"'/g' file1.txt > copyfile1.txt
```

But this does not work because the PATH variable contains forward slashes. Using information [from here](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/130495-sed-variable-backslash.html) I have tried first doing a substitution like this:

```
FORMATTED_PATH=$(echo "${PATH}" | sed 's/\//\/\//g')
```

first, and then used `FORMATTED_PATH` instead of `PATH` but then the find and replace does not work (no error messages, new file is empty). And in the logging `FORMATTED_PATH = //path1//` (which I think is correct).

How can I do this find and replace using variables containing forward slashes?

(I found out [via this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584894/sed-scripting-environment-variable-substitution) that I needed to close the single quote, use double quotes around the variable and then open the single quote again. But this does not help with the forward slashes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code was so nearly right. Instead of:

```
FORMATTED_PATH=$(echo "${PATH}" | sed 's/\//\/\//g')
```

I should have had:

```
FORMATTED_PATH=$(echo "${PATH}" | sed 's/\//\\\//g')
```

This then produces the correct logging of: `FORMATTED_PATH = \/path1\/`

Answer (score 1):

awk will work too:

```
awk -F '|' -v path="$paht" -v new="$new_value" '{
    if ($1 == path) {print path FS new}
    else {print}
}' file1.txt > copyfile1.txt
```

Also, don't use all-caps for your shell variables: you have wiped out your shell's `PATH` variable used to find programs..

Comment: Thx Glenn, will check this out. Also thanks for PATH tip...  *blushes*

Answer (score 1):

Usually the `sed`'s `s` command (as in `s///`) supports using separators other than `/`. For example:

```
$ echo '/path1/|value1' | sed 's,\(/path1/|\).*,\1value2,'
/path1/|value2
$
```

This is very convenient when dealing with file pathnames which include `/` chars.